# rails query only if nested resource exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, controller

I have a rails app. I would like to display the user only if the profile exists (user has_one profile). According to my best knowledge, since I have in group of in my index.html.erb I can't just simply use <%if user.profile %>, so I want to filter it in the controller.

How should I change the query to fetch only those users from the db who have profile?

In general what is the best way to check if the nested resource exists? Doing it in controller with query or just doing it in the view?

users/controller.rb

```
def index
    @q_users = User.ransack(params[:q])
    @users = @q_users.result(distinct: true).includes(:profile).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 12)
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<div class="user-profile-index" style="padding-right:20px;padding-left:20px;">
  <% @users.each_slice(3) do |users_for_row| %>
    <div class="row">
      <%= render :partial => "user", :collection => users_for_row, as: :user %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

_user.html.erb

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <%= link_to user do %>
    <div class="panel panel-info">
      <div class="panel-heading">
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <% if user.profile %>
        <% if user.profile.avatar %>
          <%= image_tag user.profile.avatar.url(:base_thumb), class: "avatar" %>
        <% end %>
        <h4><%= user.profile.first_name %> <%= user.profile.last_name %></h4>
        <h5><%= user.profile.company %></h5>
        <% end %>
        <h5><%= user.email %></h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

user.rb

```
has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
```

profile.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

Comment: Is `profile` a field on `user` or is it separate model? Can you show the relevant model code?

Comment: Patrick, models added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `includes(:profile)` with:

```
joins(:profile).preload(:profile)
```

`joins` will give you INNER JOIN, which will select only users that have profiles. `preload` will preload profiles that where found in `joins` (to avoid N+1 problem).
You can also move this joins into a separate scope in User model, e.g. `with_profile`.

Comment: I believe that the `where` is not necessary here since the conditions will be generate from the call to `join`.  `joins(:profile).preload(:profile)` should work.